# Intent to Docusign in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to open the image using Share Intent. DocuSign app is listed in the share bottom sheet. But when i clicked it, displays an alert saying "There was an error retrieving the document data". Please help me to open the image in DocuSign app.

```
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
  shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share text");
  shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
  shareIntent.setType("image/png");
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open multiple files at a time in Docusign app. Send single file.

Use this

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("your file path here"));
```

instead of

```
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```